# MeteorJS does not connect with the MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm new in MeteorJS so this question might be dumb, but anyway.
I've tried several times to follow tutorials about building a beginner's app with meteorJS, even the one provided at the front page of meteor.com .
But this line of code

```
Something = new Meteor.Collection("something");
```

does not seem to work by the time a)my meteor app runs but finds (and returns) no data from this mongodb collection and b)when I type into the meteor app directory `"meteor mongo"` and I try to manually insert some data into this collection, it returns me an undefined collection error.

I've installed MeteorJS just by using `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` , which as I know installs also a meteor-mongodb version.

After many hours of googling, I can admit that apparently I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot find out what!
Any advice/help here would be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have given a very small piece of the code. There should be publication/subscription (if autopublish is removed), template, event handler (insert call) code snippets. Also did you try inserting from the browser, if so, how did you try it?

Comment: My code is the code that meteor.com gives at the front page example: http://pastebin.com/n3aWP7p0 . 
Also, I did not try to insert anything from the browser.

Comment: can you try to do `Something.insert({foo: "bar"})` and then `Something.find().fetch()` from the browser console?

Comment: Yes! Now it worked!! I told ya so, it was such a dumb question :/ Thank you so much! But please, if you know please explain to me why using the meteor-mongo shell it didn't work?

Comment: Don't beat yourself, we've all been there. You'll be answering questions here in a few weeks. Ok, on meteor mongo shell, can you try `db.something.insert({baz: "fubar"})` if this works, I'll go ahead and explain it in the answer, if not we'll find out what's wrong together.

Comment: Yeap, that also worked! I was missing the "db." prefix when i was trying to insert something before! Thank you for all your help Serkan! :D

Comment: No problem, I created the answer to sum it all up. Let me know if there is anything that needs further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple example on meteor homepage uses two default packages called `autopublish` and `insecure` which allow you to quickly mock up applications that set publish/subscribe patterns for you behind the scenes and assume that visitors are trusted.

That being said, as soon as you set up your collection using:

```
CollectionNameMeteor = new Meteor.Collection("collection-name-mongo");
```

Meteor implements http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection which is a mongodb compliant representation of your collection but the syntax is a little bit different.

While a direct query on mongodb with mongodb's syntax `db.collection-name-mongo.find()` returns a document, meteor's collection api uses a slightly different syntax `CollectionNameMeteor.find()` and returns a cursor as described here http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection_cursor and to retrieve the document from that cursor, you need to `CollectionNameMeteor.find().fetch()` which fetches the result as an array.

But you would normally use the cursor reference on your meteor code since most of meteor's magic relies on that.

Similarly, to do an insert, on the mongodb shell you'd do

```
db.collection-name-mongo.insert({foo: "bar"})
```

Whereas on meteor, you'd do

```
CollectionNameMeteor.insert({foo: "bar"})
```

Which also has a useful callback http://docs.meteor.com/#insert